# RMSEP only for comparison?

Tags: multiple-regression, predictive-models

Is RMSEP only for comparison between regression models, when deciding which model should be used for prediction, or can it be used to tell how "good" your model is at predicting?

in short, I have built a multiple linear regression model, having used  200 observations.

$y=\alpha + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + \beta_3 x_3$

$y$ is measured in centimeters. I have found that RMSEP (with leave one out) is about 1 cm. Is my model good at predicting values? I have found that the mean of all my observations is about 170 cm and I was thinking maybe a good way is to relate RMSEP to the mean 170 so that 1/170 might not seem much. However, what is "much" is very dependent on one's preferences.

What would you say?

Comment: You have the main point here: RMSE (in any flavour) is measured on the same scale, and with the same units of measurement, as the response variable. Thus you can think of the typical error in substantive terms (even with just one model). The idea is that you should know something about the response variable -- or if not can get the people with the problem to talk about it. Thus to pick absurd extremes, a model purporting to predict human heights with RMSE 50 cm is too poor to be taken seriously, while one with 1 mm was produced by a cheat, a charlatan or someone too careless to be trusted.